# How can I load a stylesheet through ajax AND have a callback when the loading is done

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, cors

I need to load a bunch of CSS files through ajax and call an animation when the stylesheet has finished loading, otherwise the animation will fail.

What I have done so and used to work pretty well until I came accross doing this cross-domain is this:

```
$.get(resource.url, {cache:true}, function(css) {
    //Now that the stylesheet is in the browser cache, it will load instantly:  

    $("head").append($("<link>",{
       rel: "stylesheet",
       type: "text/css",
       href: resource.url
    }));

}).then(function(){
   //Animation here that depends on the loaded css
});
```

This works fine as long as `resource.url` is on the same domain. Once I try to load the css from another domain `$.get` will fail like this:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://example.com/style.css. Origin https://example.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

So I have tried to add CORS into the header through `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    #cross domain access is okay for resources (#107)
    <FilesMatch "\.(css|js)$"> 
        Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

This adds the CORS header to all CSS and JS resources.

For some reason [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) doesn't seem to have an effect on either chrome or firefox (newest versions).

I also came to notice that same domain policy is not enforced when doing `$.getScript` for js files, but it is for `$.get`:

```
$.get("https://example.com/script.js", {cache: false}, $.noop, "script"); 

//works regardless of CORS
```

but:

```
$.get("https://example.com/script.js", {cache: false}, $.noop); 

//does not work (cross domain policy violation)
```

So since CORS is not widely supported and doesn't even seem solve the problem for a modern browser, I need something that behaves like `$.getScript`, but for CSS stylesheets.

It needs to be **asynchronous** and have a callback mechanism.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance...

Comment: To clarify: your page on `foo.com` is performing a fetch for a CSS resource on some other domain `bar.com`.  You have added the CORS headers to the pages on `bar.com`, correct?

Comment: @apsillers i've added the headers to the css resources. Was it supposed to be on the html pages?

Comment: No, I just wanted to make sure that you weren't mistakenly setting the CORS headers on the page/domain that is *performing* the fetch.  You need to set CORS headers for the cross-domain resource that is *being fetched*, meaning that you must control that cross-domain resource.  CORS is a way of saying, "hey, everyone, it's okay to access this resource in a cross-domain way," *not* a way of saying "okay, page on my domain, go ahead an access whatever domains you want".  You didn't make it clear which you were trying to do, so I wanted to clarify that.

Comment: @apsillers, good that's what I thought and that how I've implemented it. The latter wouldn't make sense at all...

Comment: Okay, great.  Writing an answer now!

Comment: Great, looking forward to it. Thank you.

Comment: As far as the CORS is concerned -- not my cup of joe. However, I'd like to share (what I think) is some valuable knowledge. jQuery's `append()` is an synchronous function. Meaning that nothing will execute until the append has been completed. This means that you don't need any `then` statement, just put the `animate()` after the `$('head').append()` function.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy yes you are right, but the way it is really implemented (i've just eded the relevant snippets here) is like this: `return $.get(...,function(){...});` and the then is put like this: `$.getStyleSheet(...).then();, but thx. Also this is not so much about CORS. CORS is just a reason why I the current method doesn't work the but the solution to it shouldn't be related to cors as old browsers (and IE ofc) don't support it.

Comment: @d_inevitable You, sir, are a gentlemen and a scholar. I wish you the very best!

Comment: I think JsFiddle.net already has a solution for including stylesheets and/or other resources such as JS. You can view-source their site.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`$.get` uses Ajax, which must obey the Same-Origin Policy.

`$.getScript` *normally* uses Ajax, *but* it also has a fallback option for cross-domain use only.  Scripts imported via `<script>` tag are not subject to Same-Origin rules, so jQuery just adds a `<script>` tag to the page and sets its `src` attribute to the requested script URL.

The same exemption is made for CSS resources loaded in through `<link>` tags.  In a perfect world, you should be able to 1) make a new `<link>` element, 2) set its `href` attribute to the right URL and 3) listen for a `load` event on that element.  I've added a callback to [this solution](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-getscript-12-1-2010) from the jQuery forums:

```
// note: non-compatible example code, see below for better code
jQuery.getCSS = function( url, media, callback ) {
    jQuery( document.createElement('link') ).attr({
        href: url,
        media: media || 'screen',
        type: 'text/css',
        rel: 'stylesheet'
    }).appendTo('head')
    .on("load", callback);
};
```

**One small problem here:** it doesn't work cross-browser.  `<link>` tags do not fire `load` events in all browsers -- see the [jQuery bug report](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/7519)  for the `$.getCSS` function that could have been.

So, the general-case [workaround is a bit insane](http://www.backalleycoder.com/2011/03/20/link-tag-css-stylesheet-load-event/): add the CSS URL as the source of a new `<img>` tag and listen for its `onerror` handler:

```
// correct code!
jQuery.getCSS = function( url, media, callback ) {
    jQuery( document.createElement('link') ).attr({
        href: url,
        media: media || 'screen',
        type: 'text/css',
        rel: 'stylesheet'
    }).appendTo('head');

    jQuery( document.createElement('img') ).attr('src', url)
    .on("error", callback);
};
```

You could also add a bit of optimization and listen for `load` event on the `<link>` (for browsers that support it) *and* an `error` event on the `<img>` (for those that don't), and put some logic in place to ensure the callback is only ever called once, in case both events occur.

As for making `$.getCSS` return a deferred object, that's a bit out of my area of expertise, but there's no theoretical reason why it couldn't be done.

Comment: hey thanks a lot, this should work. Returning a promise object shouldn't be a problem with this. But, it hits the server twice, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, it does, but that's price we must pay for not having `load` events on our `<link>` elements, sadly.  However, if your browser/server is smart about caching, it should only *download* the content of the CSS file once; the second request should return a 304 Not Modified message.

Comment: Another solution that is not generalizable (and requires CSS3) is to include an animation in your CSS file that applies to a hidden element in your page.  Listen for the `animationstart` event on that hidden element, and you'll know that the CSS file has loaded.  Again, this solution requires planned cooperation between the stylesheet and the page itself, it's not a good general solution to pull in any CSS into any page.

Comment: +1 definitely worth an up-vote for now. I will leave this open for a while, to see if there are other ideas/objections.

Comment: Okay it works in ff and is cached properly according to firebug's net panel. http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Net_Panel

Comment: Just to clarify, if you're using the img error event method, the request, once cached, is never fired twice after the initial load on the user's device. If your site is something that is always hit by fresh cache users a zillion times, it might matter, but some browsers don't even request it twice - they look and see the exact same resource is in the queue and use that.

Answer (score 0):

Put together my own implementation of apsillers' answer using a deferred rather than creating a jQuery plugin.

```
fetchStyleSheet(url, media = 'screen') {
    let $dfd = $.Deferred(),
        finish = () => $dfd.resolve(),
        $link = $(document.createElement('link'))
            .attr({
                media,
                type: 'text/css',
                rel: 'stylesheet'
            })
            .on('load', 'error', finish)
            .appendTo('head'),
        $img = $(document.createElement('img'))
            .on('error', finish); // Support browsers that don't fire events on link elements

    $link[0].href = $img[0].src = url;
    return $dfd.promise();
}

fetchStyleSheet('/url/to/my/stylesheet.css').done(() => {
    // Stuff after the sheet has loaded
});
```

This topic is several years old, and I dunno if the backup event on the img is still necessary, but it seemed fairly trivial to implement.

For my specific use-case, I don't actually care if the sheet failed to load so both cases are resolved. If you wanted to handle the cases separately, you could pass an argument to the `finish` handler to resolve/reject appropriately.